# how to diagnose and fix a broken flac file

Tags: bash, audio, corruption, flac

I have an album of flac files, but track 15 appears to be broken or corrupted, it wont play in vlc media player on my windows 10 computer, and I have tried importing it to Audacity but with no luck.
[image]

Does anyone know how I can diagnose and fix the file? Since I can see it is 15,444 KB in size I think it might be salvageable. I downloaded the `$ flac` bash command line tool and can use that, I'm just not sure how to diagnose the issue and potentially fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used a program called FLAC FRONTEND to find the error, then i decoded the file to wav, and re-encoded it back to flac

https://www.blisshq.com/music-library-management-blog/2015/03/31/test-flacs-corruption/